# Залоги глагола в русском языке

Tags: причастия

Уместно ли в русском языке употреблять причастия в предложении в разных залогах и времени, если причастия относятся к одному существительному.

Пример.

«Серьезный возраст *прожившего жизнь и сформированный(ого) временем* человека, со своими взглядами, со своей жизненной философией, со своими ориентирами...»

Есть ли здесь ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Серьезный возраст прожившего жизнь и сформированн**ого** временем человека, со своими взглядами, со своей жизненной философией, со своими ориентирами... - ошибки нет.

Страдательное и действительное причастия могут употребляться рядом. Главное, чтобы соблюдалась видо-временная соотнесённость: совершенный и несовершенный вид глаголов и их форм, настоящее и прошедшее время в одном предложении некорректны.